# Choosing at compile time which function to call using templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I am using C++11, and was trying to set up a generic `Handle` class in my application, where it is sometimes possible to convert handles with different underlying types, but only if the underlying types are related as ancestor/descendant, otherwise attempts to convert should simply fail.  I also need a function that will never fail that tells me if a conversion is even possible between the two types.   In particular, I do not want the underlying type to try to do any conversion to types that are not within its own ancestry/descendant lines, so I was thinking if I defined a templated functor on a boolean that told me at compile time whether the types were related, and used template specialization to reject the conversion if they are not related, or to forward the conversion request to the underlying type if they are related.  Each base class contains a templated conversion function that knows how to convert to each of the corresponding types in it hierarchy as well as a templated boolean function that indicates if such conversion is possible based on the internal states of the class instance.

What I put together looks like this:

```
template<class T>
class MyHandle {
public:
    ...
    template<bool> struct can_be_ref {    
        template<class U> bool operator()(const MyHandle *, const U*) const
        {
        }
    };

    template<bool> struct as_ref {
        template<class U> MyHandle<U> operator()(const MyHandle *, const U*) const
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Illegal type conversion");
        }
    };
    template<class U> bool can_be();
    template<class U> MyHandle<U> as();
private:
    const T* get_member_reference() const;
};

template<class T> struct MyHandle<T>::can_be_ref<true> {    
    template<class U> bool operator()(const MyHandle<T> *ptr, const U*)
    {
        ptr->get_member_reference()->can_be<U>();
    }
};

template<class T> struct MyHandle<T>::as_ref<true> {    
    template<class U> MyHandle<U> operator()(const MyHandle<T> *ptr, const U*) const
    {
        return ptr->get_member_reference()->as<U>();
    }
};

template<class T> template<class U> bool MyHandle<T>::can_be()
{
    return can_be_ref < std::is_base_of<T, U>::value || std::is_base_of<U, T>::value > ()(this, reinterpret_cast<const U *> (nullptr));
}

template<class T> template<class U> MyHandle<U> MyHandle<T>::as()
{
    return as_ref < std::is_base_of<T, U>::value || std::is_base_of<U, T>::value > ()(this, reinterpret_cast<const U *> (nullptr));
}
```

This does not compile, however, and I don't know what I am doing wrong.  The failure happens where I try to specialize the `can_be_ref` and `as_ref` structs, where the compiler complains about too few template parameter lists.

Hopefully, what I am wanting to do is clear between the explanation I've offered and this fragment of code that regrettable does not work, but it is the only way I can think of to describe what I am trying to do.   What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Clarification, say that I have the following class Hierarchies:

```
class A {
public:
  template<class U> bool can_be();
  template<class U> MyHandle<U> as();
...
};

class B : public A{
...
};

class C {
public:
  template<class U> bool can_be();
  template<class U> MyHandle<U> as();
...
};
```

Each hierarchy has a `can_be` and `as` method defined that only concerns itself with the items in its hierarchy, and in particular could result in a compiler error in some cases if the argument to the template was not of the right type, which is why the type must be checked at compile time.
And the assume that we have the following variables defined:

```
MyHandle<A> a;
MyHandle<B> b;
MyHandle<C> c;
```

Because `a` and `b` are of related types, `A::can_be` and `A::as` can be freely used between them, but A::can_be might produce a compiler error.  Therefore, the wrapper around them in MyHandle hides this so that `MyHandle<A>::can_be<C>()` aways returns false, for example. While `MyHandle<B>::as<C>()` would always throw an exception, not even trying to generate a call to `B::as<C>` since that could result in a compilation error.

Edit:

Per Kamil's suggestion below, the solution was to migate the template definition to the surrounding class.   What I did was to create a helper template as follows:

```
template<class T,class U,bool> class MyHandleConverter
{
public:
    inline MyHandleConverter(const MyHandle<T> *) { }
    inline bool can_be() const { return false; }
    inline MyHandle<U> as() const { return MyHandle<U>(nullptr); }
};
```

I decided to forgo throwing exceptions on invalid conversions, and now each instance of MyHandle contains a void pointer called `value` that can contains a pointer to more information about the actual underlying type, which is nullptr if it is invalid, and so I can then create a partial specialization for the MyHandleConverterClass as follows:

```
template<class T,class U> class MyHandleConverter<T,U,true> {
public:
    inline MyHandleConverter(const MyHandle<T> *ref):reference(ref) { }    
    inline bool can_be() const {
        if (std::is_base_of<T,U>::value) {
            return true;
        } else if (reference->value == nullptr) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return reference->underlying_can_be((const U*)(nullptr));
        }
    }
    inline MyHandle<U> as() const { 
        if (std::is_base_of<U,T>::value) {
            return MyHandle<U>(reference->value);
        } else if (reference->value == nullptr) {
            return MyHandle<U>(nullptr);
        } else {
            return reference->underlying_as((const U*)(nullptr)); 
        }
    }
private:
    const MyHandle<T> *reference;    
};
```

Instead of throwing exceptions as I did previously, I instead return an invalid MyHandle (which has a special constructor, `MyHandle(nullptr_t)`, and the `MyHandle`'s status may be queried by a simple boolean `is_valid()` method, (and an exception optionally thrown by the caller if that is desired, which for my purposes works out to having to write fewer try.... catch blocks than if I had the `as<U>` function throw the exception itself on failure).

The MyHandle class has a templated `underlying_can_be` method and templated `underlying_as` method, which simply forward their request to the underlying class type's `can_be` or `as` methods, respectively.   It's worth noting that these methods would not even be generated by the compiler if it were not being invoked through the `MyHandleConverter<T,U,true>` class, so now the MyHandle `can_be` and `as` methods are written thus:

```
template <class T> template<class U> bool MyHandle<T>::can_be() const { 
    return MyHandleConverter<T, U, are_related_handle_types<U,T>()>(this).can_be(); 
}

template<class T> template<class U> MyHandle<U> MyHandle<T>::as() const { 
    return MyHandleConverter<T, U, are_handle_types_related<U,T>()>(this).as(); 
}
```

where `are_handle_types_related` is a templated constexpr function that returns true if calling the underlying templated types are found to be closely related enough that calling the underlying type for the MyHandle's `can_be` or `has` methods would not result in a compiler error, or in some cases a logical error that cannot be detected at compile time, or even at run time without writing complicated detection logic in each underlying types `as` and `can_be` methods, simply by detecting that the two classes are each derived from an appropriate type for the conversion process to plausibly succeed.

That way, when the types are incompatible as detected by `are_handle_types_related`, and it would be invalid to call the corresponding type's `can_be` or `as` methods, the instance of `MyHandleConverter` that is created is `MyHandleConverter<T,U,false>` which does not attempt to call the underlying class type, while `MyHandleConverter<T,U,true>` does, but will only be instantiated for classes where it was already found to be acceptable to call the underlying type's appropriate converstion function anyways.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you wish to use them. What are some valid usages? What are some some invalid usages? Posting them will be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specialize a template you have to add `template` keyword before specialisation, like:

```
template<class T> // Template parameter for 'MyHandle<T>'
template<> // No unspecialized template parameters for 'can_be_ref', but indicate that it is a template anyway
struct MyHandle<T>::can_be_ref<true> 
{    
    template<class U> bool operator()(const MyHandle<T> *ptr, const U*)
    {
        ptr->get_member_reference()->can_be<U>();
    }
};
```

However this does not compile either. According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization :

> Member or a member template may be nested within many enclosing class
>   templates. In an explicit specialization for such a member, there's a
>   template<> for every enclosing class template that is explicitly
>   specialized. In such a nested declaration, some of the levels may
>   remain unspecialized (**except that it can't specialize a class member
>   template if its enclosing class is unspecialized**)

So we cannot fully specialize a template without specializing MyHandle as well. Solution may be partial specialization of template parameters - move parameter `U` from `can_be_ref::operator()` to `can_be_ref` level :

```
template<class T>
class MyHandle
{
public:
...
    template<class U, bool>
    struct can_be_ref
    {
        bool operator()(const MyHandle<T> *ptr, const U*) const
        {
            return false;
        }
    };

    template<class U, bool>
    struct as_ref
    {
        MyHandle<U> operator()(const MyHandle<T> *, const U*) const
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Illegal type conversion");
        }
    };
...
};
```

Then we can go for a partial specialization:

```
template<class T>
template<class U>
struct MyHandle<T>::can_be_ref<U, true>
{
    bool operator()(const MyHandle<T> * ptr, const U*) const
    {
        return ptr->get_member_reference()->can_be<U>();
    }
};

template<class T>
template<class U>
struct MyHandle<T>::as_ref<U, true>
{
    MyHandle<U> operator()(const MyHandle<T> *ptr, const U*) const
    {
        return ptr->get_member_reference()->as<U>();
    }
};

template<class T>
template<class U> bool MyHandle<T>::can_be() const
{
    return can_be_ref<U,
            std::is_base_of<T, U>::value || std::is_base_of<U, T>::value>()(
            this, nullptr);
}

template<class T>
template<class U> MyHandle<U> MyHandle<T>::as()
{
    return as_ref<U,
            std::is_base_of<T, U>::value || std::is_base_of<U, T>::value>()(
            this, nullptr);
}
```

Actually when I complied it for example classes `A`,`B`,`C` complied complained on line `return ptr->get_member_reference()->can_be<U>();` that: `expected primary-expression before ')' token`. I don't really get what is the problem here. Calling it like `get_member_reference()->A::can_be<U>()` worked. A workaround that worked was to determine `U` parameter for `can_be<U>()` by passing argument of type `U`:

```
class A {
public:
  template<class U> bool can_be(const U*)
{
return can_be<U>();
}
  template<class U> MyHandle<U> as(const U*)
{
return as<U>();
}

  template<class U> bool can_be();
  template<class U> MyHandle<U> as();
};

template<class T>
    template<class U>
    struct MyHandle<T>::can_be_ref<U, true>
    {
        bool operator()(const MyHandle<T> * ptr, const U* uptr) const
        {
            return ptr->get_member_reference()->can_be(uptr);
        }
    };

    template<class T>
    template<class U>
    struct MyHandle<T>::as_ref<U, true>
    {
        MyHandle<U> operator()(const MyHandle<T> *ptr, const U* uptr) const
        {
            return ptr->get_member_reference()->as(uptr);
        }
    };
```